# NuGet API Wrapper - ProblemDetails class handling

Tags: c#, .net, api, error-handling, nuget

I'm facing an issue wrapping some of my APIs calls in different NuGet packages.

All errors returned by the APIs are using the `ProblemDetails`/`ValidationProblemDetails` classes thanks to the `Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails` package I discovered recently.

Now the issue is: When adding the API wrapper NuGet packages to my client applications, I prefer not leaving the deserialization task of the `response.Content` to them (call being successful or not).

This would produce mainly 3 response types:

- `Success` => `Expected` regular object, that can change for each method exposed by the API
- `BadRequest` => `ValidationProblemDetails`
- Any other error => `ProblemDetails`

My main issue handling the deserialization within the wrapper is that `ProblemDetails`/`ValidationProblemDetails` classes are "deeply" rooted in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core` namespace and thus in the corresponding NuGet package (no abstraction that I know of).

It seems overkill to include such a package as a direct dependency to a simple API wrapper in my opinion (but I may be wrong thinking this way, feel free to correct me).

Unfortunately, according to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7679, the situation is not bound to change anytime soon.

I've thought of making a NuGet package of my own including those classes and having it as a dependency spread across all my wrapper but I'm not very fond of this solution.

If anyone has better ideas or solutions to handle this (returning a proper `ProblemDetails` object, directly from the API wrapper), they're very welcome.

Comment: providing code would be a good start, thank you

Comment: Hi, we have the same problem as you are, we use ProblemDetails, but we do not load it from the package. Copying the code is a fine solution, then you can scale it in the way you need, there is nothing wrong about it

Comment: @Olegl Thanks for the input, I don't really like duplicating existing code though, if the class was to evolve in the ASP.NET codebase, we'd need to maintain that manually everytime in our packages... but I might end up doing it since it looks like a dead end.

Comment: @NewBie1234 while I understand  your point, I'm pretty sure code here is irrelevant (I've a dozen of packages each with different code but that are all concerned in the same way, it's really about the "generic" (not sure of the term) problem described in my post (see after again, if it clarifies?)             

The question is about how to include the ProblemDetails/ValidationProblemDetails classes that already exists in the ASP.NET codebase properly in a self-made NuGet package (By properly, I mean not including the "big" Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core package as a dependency)